# Running CodeSigned powershell scripts on target machines

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, code-signing

**Goal:** I would like to run my custom powershell scripts that are signed with a valid certificate against target machines with their powershell execution policy set to “AllSigned” without having to install another certificate on the target machine.

**Problem:** The powershell scripts will not run until I install the public key of the certificate I used to sign the scripts as a trusted publisher (lets call it MyCert.cer) on the target machine.

**Possible Misunderstanding:** I could be misunderstanding the way code siging works with my “problem” above. However I was under the impression that since windows comes with DigiCert certificates installed by default as “Trusted Root Certification Authorities”  (See image below) that all I would need for my signed scripts to work is signing them from a digicert authority. 
[image: Screenshot of TrustedRootCertAuth section of certificates]

**My Certificate details:**

- I purchased a code signing certificate from DigiCert. The certificate is valid and has an “EKU” of “Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)”.
- Certificate chain:

  [image: My Certificates cert chain]

**Final Thoughts:**  I signed the powershell scripts using the cmdlet “Set-AuthenticodeSignature” and my issued code signing certificate. The scripts will run if I install the MyCert.cer public key as a “Trusted Publisher” on the target machine. However, I would like to not have to touch the target machine and be able to run my code signed scripts against said machine. Is this possible? Have I purchased the wrong certificate for my goal? Or is an entry to the Trusted Publishers certificate store required for running code signed scripts?
Thank you for your time.

**Update:** Here is the command I used to sign the powershell scripts.

`Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath $FileToSign -IncludeChain all`

I wanted to let everyone know that I did include "All" for the includeChain. I have also tried using digiCerts timestamp server for the -TimestampServer parameter. However adding the timestamp does not make a difference for running the script. The -TimestampServer parameter as to my understanding is for when a certificate expires and need to be re-validated. However the certificate I am using is still current and not expired.

Comment: I don't have any experience with running scripts signed by a public certificate, I do have some experience with signed scripts. Within a domain I could run scripts signed with my certificate (issued from an internal CA). In technical terms there is not a lot of difference. I did had to use the -Timestamp parameter when signing the script. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-5.1 for more info. According to the documentation -IncludeChain should also work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I resigned my script using DigiCerts timestamp server and I also included "all" for the certificate chain. However both of these did not make a difference for running the script. After looking more into the documentation you linked to it appears that the -Timestamp parameter is only for when certificates expire. Here is a quote for the same document: "A time stamp prevents the script from failing if the certificate expires" However my certificate is still valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding the intended behavior of the `AllSigned` Execution Policy.  From `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies` you will see:

```
 AllSigned
 - Scripts can run.

 - Requires that all scripts and configuration files
   be signed by a trusted publisher, including scripts
   that you write on the local computer.
```

The short answer is that you'll need to trust your cert on all your computers (the easy way to do this is with Group Policy).  The Group Policy Object that you'll write will modify `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Public Key Policies\Trusted Publishers` and then you'll need to follow the instructions in the `Certificate Import Wizard`.  The key thing here is that the certificate can be traced back to the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` in your organization, so it's a *very good thing* that you bought a Digicert certificate and that your organization trusts Digicert certs.

So why does Digicert show up under Trusted Root Certification Authorities?  The answer here is pretty simple.  It means that your organization recognizes Digicert certificates and allows them to be trusted.  This doesn't mean that every single Digicert certificate automatically gets a pass, it just means that they are *allowed* to be installed to your domain.  I am gonna pick on Comodo, since they're close alphabetically and they don't show up in your screenshot.  Because Comodo also gives out digital certificates, if I were to sign my scripts with my Comodo cert and try and install that certificate across your domain, it wouldn't stick since Comodo is not a `Trusted Root Certification Authority` in your domain.

I hope that helps explain what's going on!